# React Native Push Notication - react-native-fcm - ios cannot build

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-fcm

Hello,

I'm trying to use push notification in  react native and for that, I am using react-native-fcm.

It is working on Android and it allows the receiving of notifications from firebase.

However, on IOS, I get build errors as shown in the attached photo.

I did react-native link, made sure the lib was in build phases for linked binaries and also modified the AppDelegate as mentioned in the installation steps.

Has anyone encountered the below error? I did a project clean, delete the build folder but to no avail.

[image: xcode errors]

Comment: Have you added googleservice-info.plist ? and also creating build using push enable certificates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much struggling...

The issue was not with IOS or the react-native-fcm module.

It was with an outdated pod repository.

After updating the pod repo, "pod update Firebase/Core", all the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Install pods for FCM...

https://medium.com/google-cloud/push-notification-for-react-native-bef05ea4d1d0

Please check